# LSM6DS3 gyro raw to degrees per second conversion error

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, embedded, c, imu

I am using LSM6DS3 for one of my projects with Nordic nrf52840 along with Nordic SDK. I am trying to read the gyroscope and according to my understanding the gyroscope value should not exceed the full scale value. I have configured the IMU with 500dps FS. From the datasheet I can see the mdps/LSB is 17.50. For some reason I am getting a Full scale value closer to 572.15dps. I already investigated pre existing libraries and they use a similar conversion function as well.

I am using the following conversion function.

```
static float calc_gyro(int16_t input)
{
    float output = (float)(input * 17.50f / 1000.0f);
    return output;
}
```

The input parameter is the raw value from the gyro register being read using i2c protocol.

Since I have not worked with IMUs before I cant tell whether this is normal behavior or not? Should the value go over 500dps?